# QGIS image export color issue

Tags: qgis, export

I'm having trouble exporting a map from QGIS to an image on Linux. The exported image has much stronger color contrast than inside QGIS. This occurs both on PNG and TIFF exports.

I exported by Project > Export/Import > Export Map To Image.

[image]

On the left is the exported TIFF (PNG looks the same). On the right is the map in QGIS. Notice how much darker some of the green areas are on the left image.

Is this a known issue? Is there a better way to export an image from QGIS?

EDIT: After playing around with this a while longer, it seems that there is a relationship between the size of the exported image and the degree of constrast/darkening. If I export with only 3k pixels to a side, the image looks like it does in QGIS. As I increase this, it starts to change more and more.

Comment: By default QGIS applies contrast enhancement that is based on the histogram. From the image properties - Symbology - Band Rendering - Contrast enhancement you can select "No enhancement" and then you should see the image as flat in QGIS than with another viewer.

Comment: All of my layers are rendered as either singleband pseudocolor or as hillshade. In the Symbology - Band Rendering menu these don't appear to have a contrast enhancement option.

Comment: One more note: Export to PDF works correctly. The colors in QGIS are replicated as expected.

Comment: There are min/max settings for pseudocolor as well. Test data would be appreciated.

Comment: The data I'm using for this totals about 5GB right now unfortunately. I did just update the question though. The issue seems related to the size of the exported photo.

Comment: Test data should be as small as possible. Take a sample that still makes the issue to appear.

Comment: what are you using to view the image outside QGis - does it do any "enhancement"?

Comment: The exported image also looks less detailed than the one in QGIS. Try exporting at a higher resolution and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This continues to be an issue in QGIS version 3.22.16.

I was exporting as JPEG images at 150 dpi to reduce file sizes, but the colours were 'dull.'
A solution for small file size and faithful colours is to:

1. Change the Export resolution to 150 dpi under the Layout tab.
2. Export as PDF.

One advantage for PDF is that, if you export text as text (rather than paths), you can edit text annotations in Inkscape.

Comment: Don't export as JPEG if you want to keep your colors. Have you tried a lossless raster export instead?

Comment: See the original post. TIFF is a lossless format.